# Problema al realizar operaciones con decimales

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema, use {{number_format}}
para convertir automaticamente decimales y todo bien... convierte a decimales pero cuando voy a hacer una operación obtengo error

$ NaN

TOTAL A PAGAR: $ NaN

este es el codigo...

```
    function updateList() {
        "use strict";
        var cart_items = "";
        var grandTotal = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < cart.length; j++) {
            var total_price = 0;
            total_price = cart[j].qty * Number(cart[j].price);
            grandTotal += Number(total_price);
            cart_items += '<div class="p-4 bg-white rounded"><img class="rounded bp-2" src="' + cart[j].product_image + '"><div class="flex mb-6 mt-1 justify-between items-center"><div><h3 class="text-sm font-medium">' + cart[j].product_name + '</h3> <span class="text-xs text-gray-500">' + cart[j].subtitle + '</span></div></div><div class="flex mb-2 justify-between items-center"><h4 class="text-xl font-bold">' + currency + ' ' + total_price + '</h4> <a onclick="reduceQty(' + j + ')" class="py-2 px-3 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-full text-xs text-white transition duration-200">-</a><h4 class="text-sm font-medium">' + cart[j].qty + '</h4> <a onclick="addQty(' + j + ')" class="py-2 px-3 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-full text-xs text-white transition duration-200">+</a> <a class="py-2 px-3 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-full text-xs text-white transition duration-200" onclick="removeFromCart(' + j + ')">X</a></div></div>';
        }
        cart_items += '<br> <h3 class="pl-4 pt-4 pr-4 font-bold">{{ __("TOTAL A PAGAR:") }} ' + currency + ' ' + grandTotal + '</h3>';
        $("#cart_items").html(cart_items);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que estas realizando operaciones con *String*
Javascript es delicado con eso, pero es sencillo.

Antes de realizar la operación matemática:

```
var numero='2';
console.log(numero*2);
```

Pasa tu valor a Número con **paseFloat**

```
var numero='2';
console.log(parseFloat(numero)*2);
```

Asi si es String lo pasas a Numero.